# Trouble opening new fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm having trouble with opening a new fragment when I click a button. The new fragment lies on top of the old one when I click a button on the settings. I've been through a few searches but I can't seem to fix this.

A picture and the relevant code is placed below. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Updated image (fragment not displaying properly):
[image]

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.phase1:
            Newsfeed1Fragment newFragment = new Newsfeed1Fragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_content, newFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(String.valueOf(newFragment));
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;
        case R.id.phase2b:
            Fragment newFragment1 = new NewsfeedFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = fragmentManager1.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.frame_content, newFragment1);
            fragmentTransaction1.addToBackStack(String.valueOf(newFragment1));
            fragmentTransaction1.commit();
            break;
        case R.id.phase2a:
            Fragment newFragment2 = new Newsfeed2aFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = fragmentManager2.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction2.replace(R.id.frame_content, newFragment2);
            fragmentTransaction2.addToBackStack(String.valueOf(newFragment2));
            fragmentTransaction2.commit();
            break;
        case R.id.phase3a:
            Fragment newFragment3 = new Newsfeed3aFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager3 = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction3 = fragmentManager3.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction3.replace(R.id.frame_content, newFragment3);
            fragmentTransaction3.addToBackStack(String.valueOf(newFragment3));
            fragmentTransaction3.commit();
            break;
        case R.id.phase3b:
            Fragment newFragment4 = new Newsfeed3bFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager4 = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction4 = fragmentManager4.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction4.replace(R.id.frame_content, newFragment4);
            fragmentTransaction4.addToBackStack(String.valueOf(newFragment4));
            fragmentTransaction4.commit();
            break;
        case R.id.phase4:
            Fragment newFragment5 = new Newsfeed4Fragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager5 = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction5 = fragmentManager5.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction5.replace(R.id.frame_content, newFragment5);
            fragmentTransaction5.addToBackStack(String.valueOf(newFragment5));
            fragmentTransaction5.commit();
            break;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

activity_newsfeed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_newsfeed" />

<com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
```

fragment_newsfeed:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="athena.sentineljs.com.athena.NewsfeedFragment"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_newsfeed"
>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rv" >
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: set background for LinearLayout in your fragment will fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for that! The problem seems to be solved for now but now the first card in my fragment is being cut off by the toolbar. Any thoughts on that?

It should look like this: https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipNXadI3hahP5fC35b5BHuhLBlBReYtbE6drMqtn

Comment: add following line to LinearLayout: **app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FrameLayout` by default have no background so you should define a background. By this way previous `fragment` (or view behind current `fragment`) will not visible any more.

for second problem you mentioned in comments you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334782/tablayout-header-hides-first-item-on-a-listview-in-a-fragment/38335371#38335371) thread.